# Resolving SamAccount Name from Display Name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Have a csv of LastName, FirstName and cannot seem to resolve the users to their SamAccountName.  I am getting the following error no matter how I try.  Below is the error.

I am trying to not use quest cmdlets.

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'doe, john' under: 'DC=corp,DC=company,DC=ORG'.
At line:1 char:11
+ get-aduser <<<<  "doe, john"
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (doe, john:ADUser) [Get-ADUse
   r], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: 'doe, john' under: 'DC=corp,DC=company,DC=ORG'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.
  Commands.GetADUser
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First solution** : you can use the `LDAPFilter` property

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(&(sn=Doe)(GivenName=jean Paul))'
```

**Second solution** : you can use the filter property

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "sn -eq 'Doe' -and givenName -eq 'Jean Paul'"
```

Comment: Nice!  thanks JP.  Threw those commands into a variable and then .samaccountname to get the result.